# How to share a web image with twitter iOS API?

Tags: ios, twitter

I have an iPhone app and I want the user to be able to tweet an image that the app displays. The image is already online. I'm wondering can I make the native tweet sheet show the image to the user as they type their tweet.

I know you can do [tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]] But that is only for a local image that you are uploading to twitter while you tweet right?

Comment: You don't want to add it as a url?

Comment: I tried adding the image url as a url with addURL but it doesn't show the image in the tweet sheet preview.

Comment: Yeah I know. It's a delicate situation because if you decide to download the image then send the tweet. You'd either freeze your interface until you finish the download or delay presenting the tweet sheet. Both solutions are not good UX design. Do you have a way to predict the tweet and cache the image before you need it?

Comment: I already have a UIImage version of the image. I just don't want the users to upload it every time since it's already online and thousands of users are going to be tweeting about the same image, and I want my server to track the traffic. I guess twitter doesn't let you tweet with an image that's already online hosted by someone else.